# Same size branch in chemfig

Tags: chemfig, size

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\section{I need caffeine.}

\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
\chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-H)-(*5(-N=-N(-H)-))=-(=O)-N(-H)-)}
\end{document}
```

And here is the corresponding rendering:

[image: Rendering]

### The question

My question is quiet simple: how to get the top =0 link and the bottom -H link have the same height?

As you see, the -H is shorter than the =0 one. My goal is to set them at the same size.

Comment: All bonds in your structure have identical length (and this is in line with IUPAC recommendations for drawing structural diagrams of chemical structures), it's the omitted 'C' label from carbonyl that makes the tick look longer. In the context of your question it actually somewhat makes sense since N−H bond is shorter than C=O. Also, note that the symbol for oxygen is *not* zero, rather the capital letter `O`.

Comment: If you would accept to manually play with the visual appearance, you could add [,x] as an argument to the respective bond (here x=0.8 as an example): ```\chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-H)-(*5(-N=-N(-H)-))=-(=[,0.8]O)-N(-H)-)}```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\def\bondlen{5pt} % half size of the font
\catcode`\_=11
\newcommand*{\cfl}{\bondlen/\CF_atomsep}
\catcode`\_=8

\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
    \chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-[6,\cfl]-[6,,,,red]H)-(*5(-N=-N(-H)-))=-(=[,,,,red]O)-N(-H)-)}
\end{document}
```

The red bonds are equal.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

All distances between atoms are equal. The bond between N and H looks smaller because N takes up more space than the carbon not shown in the C=O bond.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2em, bond offset=1pt}
    \chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-H)-(*5(-N=-N(-H)-))=-C(=O)-N(-H)-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make the bond closer to the chemical element symbol by using the "bond offset" option. You can also adjust the size of one or more links using "-[1.x]", where x represents how much you want the link to grow. But in this case you take the risk of deforming the molecule.

Answer (score 1):

Peraphs this have the same lenghts. There is a missing H.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}
\chemfig{
            % 1
     -[:252]N% 2
     -[:306]% 3
    =_[:234]N% 4
     -[:162]% 5
     =_[:90]% 6
               (
          -[:18]\phantom{N}% -> 2
               )
     -[:150]% 7
               (
          =[:90]O% 8
               )
     -[:210]N% 9
               (
         -[:150]H% 14
               )
     -[:270]% 10
               (
         =[:210]O% 11
               )
     -[:330]N% 12
               (
          -[:30]% -> 5
               )
     -[:270]H% 13
}
\end{document}
```